# Mongoose force validation only if data is present

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

I am creating a user model that will create different Strategies like, local, facebook, gmail... and i want every object to do his own validation but if i does not put values in lets say local, i does not want to validate this fields and get an error.

For example:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  local: {
    email    : {
      type    : String,
      required: true,
      validate: emailValidator,
      index   : {
        unique: true
      }
    },
    firstName: {
      type    : String,
      validate: nameValidator,
      required: true
    },
    password : {
      type    : String,
      validate: passwordValidator,
      required: true
    }
  },
  facebook: {
    id   : String,
    email: String,
    name : String
  }
});
```

Now when i want to save some user that come from facebook like this:

```
var newUser = new User();
newUser.facebook.id    = profile.id;
newUser.facebook.name  = profile.name.givenName;  
newUser.facebook.email = profile.emails[0].value;

newUser.save(function( err, user ) {
  if( err ) console.log(err);

  done(null, user);
});
```

I will get an error because the local object validation failed. So how i can make them not depend on each other and still validate the data when insert the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a custom validator and check if the proper strategy is set:

```
var emailValidator = [
    {
        validator: function(value) {
            if(!this.local) return true;
            return value;
        },
        msg: 'Email is required.'
    },
    {
        validator: function(value) {
            /* your current validation */
        },
        msg: 'Your error message...'
    }
];
```

Just move your current `emailValidator` logic to the second function in this array and do this to the other required fields.